# Use AWS CDK to trigger AWS Glue Worklfow from EventBridge

Tags: aws-glue, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

As mentioned in [this link](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18853), it's not supported by Level 2 constructs. But, it's possible to use Level 1 Constructs to implement it. Can anyone show me how to do it using Level 1 constructs, or give me an example? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished setting this up for my own use case. I'd be interested in hearing how others have done it is my solution seems like a sideways approach. The best I could figure out was to create a glue workflow with an EventBridge trigger. Then configure an Event rule with your workflow as the target. You should be able to configure S3 to post events directly however no events were showing up so I ended up using a intermediate Trail.

```
obj1 = events.CfnRule(self, 'tgr_id',
            #pattern to tgr on s3 Create Object events
            event_pattern={
                "source": ["aws.s3"],
                "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
                "detail": {
                    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
                    "eventName": ["PutObject", "CompleteMultipartUpload", "CopyObject", "RestoreObject"],
                    "requestParameters": {
                        "bucketName": ["bucket-name"],
                        "key": [{"prefix":"sample/"}]
                    }
                }
            },
            targets=[events.CfnRule.TargetProperty(
                arn=f'arn:aws:glue:{region}:{account-id}:workflow/{glue_workflow_name}',
                id=glue_wf_id,
                role_arn='arn:aws:iam::{account-id}:role/service-role/{role-name}'
            )]
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, Zacuchon. I also posted my code.  It uses an EventBridge Event trigger. CloudTrail is not needed in this way. But the code still looks hacky.  There might be better ways to do it.

Comment: Glad to see you got it working! I'll have to revisit my setup, I initially tried without Cloudtrail but the S3 events were not being captured by EventBridge.

Comment: I think the easy solution than to depend on CloudTrail to invoke glue workflow is to driectly use S3 events. S3 events can very well invoke Glue Workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I found. Very similar to Zcauchon's. The result looks like the one I created manually. But the code still looks hacky.

```
    trigger = glue.CfnTrigger(
        self,
        id=f"{job.name}-trigger",
        workflow_name=workflow.name,
        actions=[
            glue.CfnTrigger.ActionProperty(
                job_name=job.name,
            )
        ],
        type="EVENT",
        name=f"{job.name}-trigger",
        description=f"Scheduled run for {job.name}.",
    )

    event_pattern = {
        "source": ["aws.s3"],
        "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
        "detail": {
            "bucket": {
                "name": ["name"],
            },
            "object": {
                "key": [
                    {
                        "prefix": "prefix"
                    }
                ]
            },
        },
    }
    workflow_arn = (
        f"arn:aws:glue:{self.region}:{self.account}:workflow/{workflow_id}"
    )
    role = self._create_iam_role(workflow_arn)
    rule = CfnRule(
        self,
        "id",
        event_pattern=event_pattern,
        name="name",
        role_arn=role.attr_arn,
        targets=[
            CfnRule.TargetProperty(
                arn=workflow_arn,
                id="id",
                role_arn=role.attr_arn,
            )
        ],
    )
```

Comment: hey, is there way we pass the any attribute of Event Payload say S3 bucket name to workflow and access same in any of workflow job ?